# which is faster to find a random string: random line order or sorted?

Tags: grep

We want to find a random string, e.g.: `"ASDF555"`. We have a very BIG file with unique lines containing this string. Which one is faster (in time, with an easy grep command) to find the mentioned string? If the "BIG file" is:

1. sorted
2. or random?

Of course, the ASDF555 could be anything!

We are thinking of that it's faster to have the lines in random order, since the string could be random too. But we cannot prove this idea..

Comment: If you know the number then it's not random anymore. http://xkcd.com/221/ . Sorted file enables faster search.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` does not "know" your file is sorted, so it needs to go over it line by line - so the fact it's sorted is inconsequential. To rephrase - the fact that a file is sorted cannot harm your search speed - you can also go over a file line by line until you find the desired string.

However, if the file is indeed sorted, you may implement a better searching algorithm (e.g., binary searching) instead of using `grep`.